# get matching records Find in set matching multiple different set values

Tags: mysql

```
Table 1
matchID | sub1
   111  | KK Nagar,Valasaravakkam,Valasaravakkam
   112  | Vadapalani,Anna Nagar,Kodambakkam,Nungambakkam,West Mambalam,T Nagar,Virugambakkam



Table 2
   matchID | sub1
    2001   | Anna Nagar,Kodambakkam
    2002   | Kolathur,Thirunagar,T Nagar
```

Get matching records Find in set matching multiple different set values

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: The question is too vague to answer. Also please try to include a solution that you have already tried so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. i want to compare two tables. any one matching that table then i want to select  the records.

Comment: That Anna Nagar is in both table1 and table2. then select that row ..how to fetch row?